# how to connect to (private) IP adress MySQL Server?

Tags: mysql, ip

I have a MySQL Server on some workplace running, now I want to connect to it from my homeplace, get the databases, etc... 
I have the IPAdress of the workplace computer, but I cannot get access to it from my home MySQL Program if I enter the ip-adress in the connection string...
seems not to be accessible from publice.. is it possible to do it nevertheless? or impossible?

Comment: "private" IP? as in 192.168.x.x? 10.x.x.x? 172.16? Those are NOT routeable over the public internet and cannot be connected to from "outside".

Comment: You need to use the public IP of your workplace, and configure port forwarding on the firewall to connect to the server's private address.

Answer (score 2):

With MySQL you need to grant access to the IP you're trying to connect to it from..

```
GRANT USAGE ON *.* to root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx IDENTIFIED BY 'rootPassword';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Where XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX is the IP of the machine your trying to connect from, which you can find out by typing in google, "whatsmyip"

If you have a firewall enabled on your workstation, you also must permit your IP in the firewall as well.

Comment: ok is there a consistens answer? I have already granted privileges to my private IP-Adress, but still cannot connect because I cannot reach the server's IP-Adress (the server runs on some desktop PC with a private IP-Adress), not reachable from outside LAN-Area I suppose... so what are the steps that I have to do? after granting access to my ip?

Answer (score 0):

You need also change `bind-address` in MySQL configuration. Default MySQL is running on `localhost (127.0.0.1)`, you need change it to `0.0.0.0 (all interfaces)`.

If you don't have public address IP, you need use some VPN, read another topic: https://askubuntu.com/questions/64016/access-workstations-without-public-ip-maybe-with-vpn